# How do I load a previous save?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Can I get back to the main menu when playing *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*? I want to go back to a previous save point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to go back to the main menu to load an older save file. Open up your inventory page and change to the page on the left to "System". There you will have the option to manually save your game or load a previous save point.